# Как правильнее сделать хелпер ввода данных

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка, инспекция-кода, bootstrap4

Есть ли какие-либо плагины для такого рода хелперов? или весь код на js|jQuery ручками нужно писать? А так же интересуют предложения по улучшению кода.

```js
let mass = [{"name":"a1","value":12},{"name":"a2","value":1412},{"name":"a3","value":42},{"name":"a4","value":23}];

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#inp").on('input', function(){
    $(".helper").empty();
    /// идет ajax запрос и получаем данные с сервера (перейду сразу к данным)
    mass.forEach(e => {
      $(".helper").append(
        '<p data-val="'+ e.value +'">' + e.name +'</p>'
      );
    });
    $(".helper").show();
  });
  
  $("body").on("click",".helper p",function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().find("input").val($(this).text());
    $(".helper").hide();
  });
  
});
```

```css
.helper p:hover {
  background-color:blue;
  color:white;
}

.helper {
  display:none;
  height:auto;
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="inp" />
  <div class="helper"><div>
</div>
```

Comment: любой дродаун с фильтром, на то же jquery есть плагины

Comment: https://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/autosuggest/